# Ubuntu 14.04 on hp pavillion dm4 will not connect to the internet

Tags: wireless, 14.04

The computer originally had windows 7 on it then I installed ubuntu. Once the setup was complete I tried to connect to the internet and it will not connect to my home network.

Comment: wireless or ethernet?

Comment: You have a broadcom wireless card. Please follow the steps provided in http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers to solve your issue.

Comment: wireless. And that link did not help when the command is typed in terminal it says unable to locate package